# Leave 'amp;' out of my link in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, help

I want to link to a Typeform survey using a generated link that includes Fname, Company and Account Manager.
I got the link working, but when I send out an email, Marketing cloud includes amp; in the link. Because it does that, Typeform does only read the first part of the link.

This is what I want the link to look like:

```
LINK.com...#name=Peter&company=Archery%20Supplies&accountmanager=Jasper%20Dalen
```

This is how it comes out now:

```
LINK.com...#name=Peter&amp;company=Archery%20Supplies&amp;accountmanager=Jasper%20Dalen
```

Comment: Show us how you generate that link

Comment: Sure, this is the link that I get when sharing my Typeform: https://cpkcx2lng5p.typeform.com/to/Yh5v8zdn#name=xxxxx&company=xxxxx&accountmanager=xxxxx

On the xxxxx's, I use the info in the selected data source in Marketing Cloud to generate the first name, company name and account manager.
In my preview, the link works because it only places the info from the data source on the x's. But when I send an email the link changes including amp;.